# android edittext focus border on multiple edittext widgets

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, border

I have a set of EditText widgets on my activity view, each on a seperate TableRow in a TableView. When I select one of the EditText widgets, the others highlight as well although the focus is only on one of the EditTexts.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had, was that I was using a hidden edittext to use as a background reference for my edittext, however, they inherited the properties of the background when the edittext was highlighted. This was because multiple edittexts were using the same hidden edittext as a reference and so they all reacted in the same way.